# Question concerning group actions on left cosets

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-actions

This is directly from Dummit & Foote (pg. 118)

We now consider a generalization of the action of a group by left multiplication on the set of its elements. Let $H$ be any subgroup of $g$ and let $A$ be the set of all left cosets of $H$ in $g$. Define an action of $G$ on $A$ by

$ g \cdot aH=gaH$ for all $g \in G, aH \in A$
where $gaH$ is the left coset with representative $ga$.

Is the action permuting the left cosets of $H$ in $G$?

Comment: What do you mean by "grasping the meaning of $gaH$"? T

Comment: Sorry, that was incredibly unclear. Is $aH$ a particular left coset of $H$ in $G$? If so, does the action of left multiplication simply permute the left cosets?

Comment: $aH$ is the left coset of $H$ with representative $a$, that is, $aH=\{ah:h\in H\}$

Comment: Are you asking whether this action maps {aH} into a different coset?  If g $\in$ G is also in aH then no.  If g is not in  aH then yes.  But the net effect on the cosets is to leave you with the sames ones you had to begin with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what amounts as probably an overkill answer, realize the following:

You can define the notion of a group action on any category $\mathcal C$ as follows:

1. If $X \in \mathrm{Obj}(\mathcal C)$, define $\mathrm{Aut}(X)$ to be the collection of endomorphisms which are also isomorphisms. The group operation is composition, the endomorphism property ensures we can compose any two elements, the definition of a category ensures the existence of an identity and associativity of composition, and the isomorphism property ensures the existence of an inverse.
2. A group action of $G$ on an object $X \in \mathrm{Obj}(\mathcal C)$ is then just a group homomorphism $G \to \mathrm{Aut}(X)$. The way that we normally think about this is as $\psi: G \to \mathrm{Aut}(X)$ defines a group action by $g\cdot x = \psi(g)(x)$.

Now for any set $X$, you can define the permutation group $S_X$. The set-automorphisms can then be shown to be a subgroup of $S_X$; that is, $\mathrm{Aut}_{\textbf{Set}}(X) \subseteq S_X$, so if you prefer you may think of $\psi: G \to \mathrm{Aut}(X)$ as $\psi: G \to S_X$.

Thus the answer is affirmative, the group action permutes the cosets. More generally, every group action on a concrete category acts by permtuations.

Answer (score 0):

Every left $G$-action on a set $X$ is equivalent to a homomorphism from $G$ to $\operatorname{Sym}(X)$. So, yes, the answer to your question is affirmative. The point is that, given a left action "$\cdot$", the position:
$$g\mapsto(x\mapsto g\cdot x)$$
yields such a homomorphism, and, conversely, given such a homomorphism $\varphi$, the position:
$$(g,x)\mapsto g\cdot x:=(\varphi(g))(x)$$
yields a left $G$-action on $X$.